# Grabbing the cost with the max date grouping on number openquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to select information from another server, and insert it into a table through open query... Here is where I am at so far:

```
INSERT INTO smallprojects..PhyInv_310QADLockedDet (MasterRecid, location, partnum, qty) 
             SELECT @@IDENTITY, ld_loc, ld_part, ld_qty_oh 
             FROM OPENQUERY(LANSRHQAD, 'SELECT ld_loc,ld_part,ld_qty_oh FROM PUB.ld_det as a left outer join PUB.pt_mstr as b on a.ld_part = b.pt_part where pt_status <> ''OB'' and ld_part not like ''S%'' and ld_part not like ''N%'' and ld_loc = ''310'' ')
```

But this will insert multiple part numbers if the PUB.ld_det has multiple entries for that part, sort of like the example below:

Here is the data (PUB.ld_det):

```
Part | Date  | Qty
-------------------
1000 | 10-02 | 0
1000 | 10-03 | 2
1001 | 10-2  | 0
1001 | 10-2  | 2
```

I would like my result to be a insert into a table as:

```
Part | Qty
-------------------
1000 | 2
1001 | 2
```

Currently it is returning as:

```
Part | Qty
-----------
1000 | 0
1000 | 2
1001 | 0
1001 | 2
```

So when I go back to update this table I just have to hope it finds the right row.

How can I avoid bringing in the multiples and only bring it in with the highest date? The open query thing messes with me so much

Comment: I think it sounds like you really want to group by the part and sum the qty.  that way you could also handle if part 1002 has 3 entries with qty of 0, 1, and 2.  I presume then you'd want the result of 3 for qty, or sum(Qty).

Comment: Be careful using @@IDENTITY. If you have a trigger it is not going to do what you think. SCOPE_IDENTITY is probably a better choice. https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one simple method is you want one row per part:

```
INSERT INTO smallprojects..PhyInv_310QADLockedDet (MasterRecid, location, partnum, qty) 
     SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES @@IDENTITY, ld_loc, ld_part, ld_qty_oh 
     FROM OPENQUERY(LANSRHQAD, 'SELECT ld_loc,ld_part,ld_qty_oh FROM PUB.ld_det as a left outer join PUB.pt_mstr as b on a.ld_part = b.pt_part where pt_status <> ''OB'' and ld_part not like ''S%'' and ld_part not like ''N%'' and ld_loc = ''310'' ') 
     ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ld_part ORDER BY ld_qty_oh DESC);
```

Use `RANK()` if you want duplicates when there are ties.

Comment: So here you are ordering the parts at the top of the result set (so the duplicates come at the bottom after the first set of everypart was entered) and then selecting only the top from each part? Am I right to think this?

Comment: This does the job just as needed though!! Thanks @GordonLinoff